# Send push notification via REST API in Parse.com {"code":115,"error":"Missing the push data."}

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

When i am trying to test the REST API provided by Parse.com with Fiddler, it return an error. please find the enclosed screen capture. I can send the push notification on parse.com. but not from REST API.

Screenshot here:
http://s24.postimg.org/stwspcyir/image.jpg
http://s9.postimg.org/5r3guagh9/image.jpg

=== Follow Up ===
found the correct syntax of the JSON for push notification:

```
{"data": { "alert": "test message", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" },"channel":"abc"}
```

but i found that if the channel is empty, the notification will not work, all i have to do is create channels for the device..... is it true ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer finally:

if you have channels, provide the channel name:

```
{"data": { "alert": "321213", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" },"channel":"channel name"}
```

if there is no channels (default no channel), send to all devices:

```
{"data": { "alert": "321213", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" },"where": { "deviceType": "ios" }}
```

Comment: A question. Is free parse.com account allow for channel?

Comment: yes. i am using free account with channel for my ios push notification app