# Sending iOS Background Download PUSH Notification Using Parse and Typhoeus

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, parse-platform, typhoeus

I have the following ror code:

```
app = Publication.find_by_id(params[:background][:publication])
url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push'
body = { :aps => { "content-available" => 1 }}
body["content-name" => issue] if !issue.empty?
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url, 
          method: :post, 
          body: body.to_json, 
          headers: {  "X-Parse-Application-Id" => app.parse_application_id,
                      "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => app.parse_rest_api_key,
                      "Content-Type" => "application/json"})
request.run
result = JSON.parse(request.response.body).with_indifferent_access
```

And when I run it I get the following response from Typhoeus:

```
RESPONSE: {"code"=>115, "error"=>"Missing the push data."}
```

It's just a simple content-available push that tells the app to download latest issue. Any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to this post:

[Send push notification via REST API in Parse.com {"code":115,"error":"Missing the push data."}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981386/send-push-notification-via-rest-api-in-parse-com-code115-errormissing-th)

I think for Parse you need to have the content-available inside the data hash. At least that worked for me after adding the where as well.